# Triggering SMI interrupt from OS with a valid communication buffer

Tags: bios, uefi

I'm playing around with UEFI and SMM and currently am trying to trigger an SMI interrupt from ring 0 on an Intel NUC machine. I've been using [Chipsec](https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec) to do so but couldn't properly specify a valid communication buffer, which the SW SMI handler gets as one of its parameters.

The only clue I found in the UEFI specs is in "Appendix O - UEFI ACPI Data Table" under [Table 310. SMM Communication ACPI Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXniA.png) but the specified method doesn't seem to work. I'm taking a black box approach as I don't have access to the NUC's SMRAM.

What is the working way of successfully specifying the communication buffer for an SMI? Some code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the TianoCore/EDK II source code?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it didn't help as the EDK2 source code doesn't contain any information regarding the way the OS should specify the communication buffer

Answer (score 0):

It is a secure SMI call must be invoked, then this buffer could be retrieved. Modern UEFI BIOS provides special mechanism to present external user to get private data. This information did not reveal on any documents.